# Vuex - constants for Mutation types, but not Actions and Getters?

Tags: vue.js, constants, vuex

In the Vuex guide it is suggested to use constants for Mutation types. I was thinking about doing this for Actions and Getters too but then I realized the guide never mentions using constants for Actions and Getters.

But why not? The advantages to using constants for Actions and Getters are pretty much the same as for Mutations. So why is this not recommended explicitly? Is there something that I am missing about why you would use them for Mutations, but not Actions and Getters?

Comment: I've often wondered the same thing myself. Shame you haven't gotten an answer.

Comment: Even more than that: it would seem that using constants for mutations is unnecessary, since in most practical cases, mutations are embedded in the same file as actions, and there's little reason to call a mutation directly from outside.
On the other hand, actions will often be called through the code, and it would make sense to use constants then…

Comment: I saw projects using Actions Types like [Vue Realworld Project](https://github.com/gothinkster/vue-realworld-example-app/), but how about Getters?

It's look weird when just use on Mutations, when we use Getters and Actions outside a lot of time as @Dave pointed out